# syntax errorについて

Tags: php

以下のシンタックスエラーが発生します。

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected identifier "id", expecting "," or ";" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Portfolio\user_table.php on line 38
```

38行目の `$data['id']` 付近で何か問題かと思うのですが、`htmlspecialchars` が何か邪魔しているのかと思い、削除してみても結果は同じでした。
念のため、id="seq"を削除してみましたが結果は同じでした。
エラー原因をお教えいただけないでしょうか。

ソースを添付します。

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=ja>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>ユーザーメンテナンス</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Salon Yuri-rinの管理者ページ">
        <!--リセットcss-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ress/dist/ress.min.css">
        <!--css-->
        <link href="css/ad_style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--レスポンシブ対応-->
        <meta name="viwport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!--Googleフォント-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sawarabi+Gothic&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Shippori+Mincho:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            try{
            require_once("db_connect.php");
            $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$SERV;dbname=$DB;charset=$CHAR",$USER,$PASS);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "select id,last_name,first_name,user,password from user_table";
            $stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
            $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach($row as &$data)
                var_dump($data);
             {
                echo '<h1>','ユーザーメンテナンス','</h1>';
                echo '<form action="?" method="post">';
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<th class="header">','姓','</th>';
                echo '<th class="header">','名','</th>';
                echo '<th class="header">','ユーザー','</th>';
                echo '<th class="header">','パスワード','</th>';
                echo '<th class="header2">','<input type="submit" name="button" value="登録" formaction="user_create.php">','</th>';
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="seq" value="htmlspecialchars($data['id'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8')" id="seq">';
                echo '<td class="dt">','<input type="text" name="sei" value="htmlspecialchars($data['last_name'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8')" id="sei" readonly="readonly">','</td>';
                echo '<td class="dt">','<input type="text" name="mei" value="htmlspecialchars($data['first_name'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8')" id=mei readonly="readonly">','</td>';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="sei_kana" value="htmlspecialchars($data['last_name_kana'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8')" id="sei_kana">';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="mei_kana" value="htmlspecialchars($data['first_name_kana'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8')" id="mei_kana">';
                echo '<td class="dt">','<input type="text" name="user" value="htmlspecialchars($data['user'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8')" id="user" readonly="readonly">','</td>';
                echo '<td class="dt">','<input type="password" name="password" value="htmlspecialchars($data['password'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8')" id="password" readonly="readonly">','</td>';
                echo '<td>';
                echo '<input type=submit name=botton value="修正" formaction="user_update.php">';
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td>';
                echo '<input type=submit name=botton value="修正" formaction="user_delete.php">';
                echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
                echo "\n";
                echo '</table>';
                echo '</form>';
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){echo "次がエラーの内容です。;" .$e->getMessage();}
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

シングルクォーテーションで括られた文字列の中にシングルクォーテーションを入れ子にできないため、コンパイルエラーになります。
入れ子にしたい場合は`\'`のようにエスケープしてください。

```
echo 'a'b'c';   // コンパイルエラー
'a\'b\'c'; // OK
```

また、ご質問の例ではシングルクォーテーションの中に[htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.htmlspecialchars.php)が入っていますが、これはただの文字列として動作して式評価されません。
下記のようにhtmlspecialcharsの戻り値の文字列と通常の文字列を`.`で連結することで、求める値になりそうです。

```
<?php
$data = array('id' => '<1>');
echo '<input value="' . htmlspecialchars($data["id"], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, "UTF-8") . '" id="seq">';
?>
```

Comment: エラー解消されました。htmlspecialcharsのご指摘までしていただき、ありがとうございました。